# ¿Como saber cuando la propiedad src de una imagen cambia su valor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Lo que quiero realizar o mejor dicho saber es como puedo saber cuando mi atributo src se cambia, ya que actualmente tengo una galería de imágenes que cambian cada cierto tiempo mediante javascript.

```
    var imgArray = ["http://localhost:8080/GIBLO/Assets/Imagenes/Galeria1.jpg", "http://localhost:8080/GIBLO/Assets/Imagenes/Galeria2.jpg", "http://localhost:8080/GIBLO/Assets/Imagenes/Galeria3.jpg"];
    curIndex = 0;
    imgDuration = 5000;

function slideShow() {

    document.getElementById('Galeria').src = imgArray[curIndex];
    curIndex++;
    if (curIndex == imgArray.length) {
        curIndex = 0;
    }

    setTimeout("slideShow()", imgDuration);
}
```

Quiero saber cuando cambia mi src de mi tag img para que cada vez que cambie yo le pueda agregar un efecto a la transición.

Codigo HTML:

```
   <center><img id="Galeria" /></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la libreria https://cdn.rawgit.com/meetselva/attrchange/master/js/attrchange.js

Podrías utilizar para el atributo *src* de la etiqueta *img*

Comment: La web del pluggin es https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange